# What is the need to do a dV/dI measurement instead of numerical differentiation?

Tags: measurement

In the semiconductor industry many measurements are performed as dV/dI versus applied voltage V. Here, dV/dI donates a differential resistance measurement. What I do not understand is the need for such measurements while you can always do a numerical differentiation of standard V-I measurement. So what am I missing?

Comment: Can you describe the difference between the two methods in more detail?  Are you sure they're not the same method?

Comment: If there are two alternatives to measure a certain characteristics, why not using the most simple method ? Remember dV/dI is valid for small signals only. This can be easily accomplished, for example with a small sinus signal.

Comment: I'd guess it's instrumentation design- if you actually want the slope of the V-I curve at some point you'll probably get a better number by measuring it directly. For example, if the V-I curve covers a range 100x as much as the variation used to measure the slope you'll lose 7 bits so the measurement will be worse and/or will take longer than it would be if you amplified the small signal variation to almost fill the ADC range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerical differentiation of real data tends to cause noise problems.

It's easiest to explain in terms of a time series. You know the Fourier transform rule for derivatives is

$$\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\right) = (j\omega)\mathcal{F}\left(f(t)\right)$$

where \$\mathcal{F}(\cdot)\$ is the Fourier transform operation.

This means the transform of the derivative has more energy at higher frequencies, compared to the origianal function.

Usually, your signal is bandlimitted (or smooth), so that this doesn't cause the F.T. of the desired function to blow up. The problem is that real measurements have noise (or random errors), and almost always there is a noise component which is "white", meaning it has roughly equal energy at all frequencies. When you take the numerical derivative, you will also be taking the derivative of the white noise component. And the spectrum of the derivative of the white noise component will increase at high frequencies, often to the point that it swamps the desired signal.

To avoid this problem, you might try to smoothe or filter the data before differentiating. That will help, but the problem is still fundamentally there.

And although it's most obvious why this problem exists for time series data, the same math applies even if your data describes some other relationship like an I-V curve.

That said, I don't think it's uncommon to do differential resistance (\$\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}I}\$) measurements using numerical differentiation. If you were using a measurement system with low noise SMUs ilke an HP/Agilent/Keysight 4155 model, and use long enough integration time for each measurement point, you would likely be able to get adequate results for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

My comment above is speculation on why it may be done differently.

If you were to do it with a V-I curve data acquisition and manipulation, I don't think you'd use conventional numerical differentiation anyway. Perhaps fit the data over the range of interest in a least-squares manner to a well behaved curve such as a cubic spline and then the slope at the desired point falls out immediately. Sort of like the derivation of the central difference method of numerical differentiation.

The math horsepower to do this may not have been easily available when such instruments were designed. Today it's not much of a problem.